# Jquery: using addClass to highlight 'like' menu items

Tags: jquery, class, addclass, removeclass

My brain must be utterly broken, because I can't figure out why this isn't simple.

I have two lists-- one of categories, and one of items belonging to these categories.  I need to highlight items in the second list based on the item selected in the first, using shared classes.

Based on what I can tell, I'm missing a loop on my second list, for starters, but something else is wrong as well.  I just can't figure out the right way to use addClass and hasClass together, maybe.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dilettante/9Ux27/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it too hard, it will work like this:

```
$('.firstlevel li a').click(function() {
    var categoryID = $(this).attr("class");

    $('.firstlevel li a').removeClass("current-menu-item")
    $(this).addClass("current-menu-item")

    $('.secondlevel li a').removeClass('clicked');
    $('.secondlevel li a.' + categoryID).addClass('clicked');

});
```

[here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ux27/5/)
    ​

Comment: This is perfect. I knew I was overthinking it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there were some bugs in the code try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Ux27/6/